# Meaning of Monotone Maps in the context of algebraic theory of boolean circuits

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, definition, boolean-algebra, monotone-functions

In the paper, [Towards an Algebraic Theory of Boolean Circuits](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404903000690), by Yves Lafont, section 2.2 is Monotone maps.

In general, monotone maps mean functions that always increase/ always decrease with increasing input, and I am not able to map that definition to the treatment of monotone maps in this paper. What do they mean in this context?

I understand that they are morphisms and have two generators, one that takes {1,2} to {1} and another that takes {} to {1}.

I don't understand what these do exactly and what the general definition of a monotone map is here. In the previous section on permutations, it was easy to understand what each morphism was doing, and I would like to have a similar understanding here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that paper the author seems to use "monotone map" to mean "non-decreasing map". So the monotone maps are the functions $f:\{1,\dots, p\}\to \{1,\dots, q\}$ such that $f(x)\leq f(y)$ whenever $x\leq y$. Note that allowing non-decreasing *and* non-increasing functions wouldn't define a subcategory of the category of finite sets $\{1,\dots, n\}$, since their composition need not be monotone.

The two generators are the maps $\mu:\{1,2\}\to \{1\}$ and $\eta:\{\}\to \{1\}$ (there is only one for each type). The claim that these are generators amount to the fact that every monotone map (in the sense described above) can be described as a composition of a surjective map and an injective one. The surjective map identifies certain numbers, and thus it can be obtained as a composition of factors obtained from $\mu$, while the monotone map skips certain numbers, and thus can be obtained as a composition of factors like $\eta$.

The category described in that section is often called the *augmented simplex category*, and it is used to define augmented simplicial sets or objects. The *augmented* part comes from the empty set; if you remove the empty set you get the *simplex category* (see also the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplex+category) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_category)). Sometimes they are also called the *algebraists' simplex category* (with the empty set) and the *topologists' simplex category* (without the empty set).